# Allowing identification tool to click on symbol instead of feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

Working on a rather crowded map, I would like to ease the identification of colocated point features, each one linked to a photo. I usually have 2 or 3 photos on the same point and would like to keep this granularity as at some point I will add to each photo its source geometry and heading.

What I would like to achieve is (below a specific map scale threshold) to explode those points and let the user click on each photo by clicking on its **symbol** instead of the **feature** itself.

Otherwise the user has to click on the point, then click on the correct feature in the identification results to make sure it's the correct one, then right-click + open formular. 4 clicks instead of one is quite cumbersome and can take quite some time if this action is frequent.

This is one use case but in general I think it would be useful to identify a feature by simply clicking its symbol. There was already a close use-case in a [feature request long ago](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/3806), but I am wondering if there might be some easier solution first.

Any ideas?